# formControlName is not rendered when creating control dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-directive

I am working to create a form which will have controls rendered provided via API. The form is rendered without any issue. However `formControlName` property is missing from HTML when it is rendered. This causes issue with `mat-datepicker`. Since it requires the `formControlName` be associated with the control

Here is my template

```
      <div *ngFor="let item of list; let i=index;">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>{{item.control["Caption"]}}</mat-label>

          <input *ngIf="(item.control['Type'] == "Text")" matInput formControlName="{{item.key}}" >
          

          <input *ngIf="item.control['Type'] == 'Date'" matInput [matDatepicker]="i" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" [formControlName]="item.key"  >
          <mat-datepicker-toggle *ngIf="item.control['Type'] == 'Date'" matSuffix [for]="i"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker *ngIf="item.control['Type'] == 'Date'" #i></mat-datepicker>


        </mat-form-field>

      </div>
    </form>
```

Now the issue is that date control is rendered but calendar pop up does not appear on clicking calendar icon on control. However, if I input date manually in the control then it gets submitted correctly.

What am I missing here. I need to be able to bind `mat-datepicker` with any and all date controls that are rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your template like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; let i=index">
    
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    
      <mat-label>{{item.control["Caption"]}}</mat-label>

      <input *ngIf="item.control['Type'] == 'Text'" matInput [formControlName]="item.key" >
      
      <ng-container *ngIf="item.control['Type'] == 'Date'">
        <input  matInput [matDatepicker]="i" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" [formControlName]="item.key"  >
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="i"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #i></mat-datepicker>
      </ng-container>

    </mat-form-field>

 </div>
```

Here I used `ng-container` because it doesn't add additional tag in the DOM, you can also use `div` here but that would have added new tag in the DOM. You can inspect elements and see the difference.
Your can read more about `ng-container` [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/)

Comment: Thank you. This solved my issue. Can you please comment how or why ng-container in this case is needed? May be a link to some document/discussion?

Comment: You were using diff `ngIf`, I think that was causing the issue, You just had to render your `input`, `mat-datepicker-toggle`, `mat-datepicker` together. Also updated my answer with more description